# Scrolling grid view hides other control on top of activity in android

Tags: android, gridview, scroll, scrollview

[image: Android screen 1 & 2]

On scrolling down gridView.

I want to scroll my three tabs on top as shown in second image.

And on scrolling up back shows that again like first image.

I have checked paralloid library, but not sure if it solves this problem or not.

Same functionality i found in google+ android app. In profile page on scrolling tab scroll till they reach on top. after that list view scrolls.

Answer (score 0):

[GridView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/GridView.html) already has scrolling built into it, so its children should scroll separately than its siblings by default. No extra library should be needed for scrolling down, although scrolling horizontally is a separate issue.

Comment: You didn't understand my question. After many searches I found out that I need a parallax affect like thing. But hiding the above view pager control slowly is not necessary.